# How to pass data to nested promises in jquery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, promise

I have a code like this :

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  promise.when(firstoperation()).then(function(){
  Need to use data[i] here.

 });
}
```

Its a nested asynchronous function, is there anyway to pass the data to it? without making the data global??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures

Comment: No need to wrap with `when`